# pvlib for BSRN datasets retrievable via PANGAEA

Tags: pvlib

I signed up for a PANGAEA user account to access https://dataportals.pangaea.de/bsrn/ using pvlib

```
import pvlib
import pandas

df, meta = pvlib.iotools.get_bsrn(
    station='CAB',  
    start=pd.Timestamp(2020,1,1),
    end=pd.Timestamp(2020,6,1),
    username='redacted',  
    password='redacted',  
)
```

after replacing my username and password, I got this error `error_perm: 530 Login incorrect.`

What I am doing wrong! any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that there is a problem logging in, which means that the username and password combination you are using is incorrect. The pvlib function retrieves data from the FTP server and not Pangea, so the credentials may not be the same. The correct credentials can be obtained by contacting the BSRN: https://bsrn.awi.de/data/data-retrieval-via-ftp/.

Comment: It is too confusing to create an account! I emailed  Amelie Driemel and I have not got any response! any other ways to have the account

Comment: No emailing Amelie is the only way to get the credentials.

Comment: Great! I just got the response from Amelie. Thank you so much! It really helps

Comment: is there any difference between the BSRN dataset and SURFRAD dataset

Comment: The BSRN is a global network, whereas SURFRAD is a local network of stations in the US. As a matter of fact all of the SURFRAD stations are part of the BSRN network. The files from the SUFRAD FTP server are more timely and probably contain more parameters. Otherwise, the data should generally be the same.